# How can I debug of adjustOHLC()

Tags: r, quantmod

I am learning quantmod package. I wrote following codes, but R shows me error. Please help me!

```
getSymbols("AMZN", from = "2010-01-01", to = "2019-12-20", src = "yahoo")
AMZN_adj = adjustOHLC(AMZN)
```

The error is

```
Error in vapply(parse(text = fr[, 2]), eval, numeric(1)) : 
  values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 3
In addition: Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmYhsTS\file964478a68e'
```

I have check the source code of the function adjustOHLC(), I couldn't find vapply(parse()) anywhere.

Can someone help me to explain what happens in my code?

Comment: Hi! I've got the same error running `quantmod::getDividends("VTI")` which worked before! Hope we find a solution...

Comment: Seems like the dev version of `quantmod` has this issue already fixed, at least from my side: https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod

Comment: Any luck with this error? I'm having the same error with the example of adjustOHLC with AAPL even installing de development version.